# Manage Database Transactions

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, transactions

We are working on a PostgreSQL database. We have thousands of records to update in the table. Since we are performing validations, we have to commit records one by one.

The problem is if there are 10000 records and error occurs at the record number 9000, we have 8999 records committed to the database. We do not want to keep halfway processed data.

How can we implement a feature so that it will rollback everything if an error occurs? I know we cannot rollback if the record is committed. I need a different approach.

Comment: `BEGIN; <DO MANY INSERTS> COMMIT;`. If a error happens in <DO MANY INSERTS> issue `ROLLBACK`;

Comment: I am calling these statements from Java code so I cannot do like this. I have to process statements one by one.

Comment: Yes you can see: [JDBC transactions](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-jdbc/transaction/) or [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239555/postgresql-transaction-handling-with-java).

Comment: Thanks so much, Adrian. I will try this.

Comment: I doubt that you have to `COMMIT` rows one by one. Please describe the reason for this requirement in detail.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver (re your first comment): That you can call `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` explicitly, does not mean you *should*, the JDBC specification says that commits should be handled through the JDBC API. Failing to do so can result in undefined behaviour in a driver.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, at the time the comment was made the OP had not indicated they where using Java(JDBC). In any case it was a generic suggestion that still applies even if going through the API.

Answer (score 2):

> How can we implement a feature so that it will rollback everything if an error occurs?

This is a textbook example of a transaction.

Well, don't commit every changed row. Start a transaction before the loop, run your updates. If no exception is thrown, commit. Otherwise roll back.

Something along the lines:

```
Connection con = ...; // get the connection.
con.setAutocommit(false); // start a transaction
try (Statement stmt = ...;) {
  while (more stuff to do) {
    stmt.executeUpdate("...."); // do your update
  }
  con.commit(); // commit all updates 
} catch (SQLException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace(); // this should be a call to your logger 
  con.rollback();
}
```

You also might want to go through [this tutorial](https://mkyong.com/tutorials/jdbc-tutorials/) especially the chapter about [transactions](https://mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-transaction-example/)

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I will look into this and try it.